# ASP Drop Down collapses after first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP Drop Down List that opens then immediately collapses on one click. I'm using a Drop Down on another page with the same CssClass, and it's working fine (first click expands the DDL and the second click collapses it). Anyone have any idea what could be happening? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or input.

```
<label>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbToAccount" runat="server" GroupName="rbTo" />
   Account
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlToAccount" runat="server" CssClass="span4 m-wrap">      
   </asp:DropDownList>
</label>
```

Comment: "Anyone have any idea what could be happening?" - yes of course, please share your code.

Comment: Provide code please.  Also, can you tell me if you are using just the 'asp:DropDownMenu' and/or a jquery extended solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jQuery to check a radio button when a drop down is clicked.

Comment: I believe it is related to the radio button being changed. After the first click, the rb changes, and the ddl expands and collapses. I'm thinking it expands, the rb changed, then it collapses very quickly.

Comment: As sugested by Sudhakar, wrap only the radio button with the label, leave the dropdown outside, or with it's own label.

Comment: Thanks so much @Sudhakar and @Hanlet!! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
   <label></label> 
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbToAccount" runat="server" GroupName="rbTo" />
   Account
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlToAccount" runat="server" CssClass="span4 m-wrap">      
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

is the event tied to a Jquery function??
It sounds like on dropdown list change it is causing a postback, which then is refreshing the page to it's original state. Try adding `OnClientClick="return false"` as an attribute to the ddl control